# Aggregate logs message with same timestamp with AWS CloudWatch CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have this query:
`display @timestamp, @message | sort @timestamp asc | filter @message not like "GET / HTTP/1.1"'`
But some logs messages are split in several `@message` field, even if their `@timestamp` field is the same.

Is it possible to aggregate each `@message` with same `@timestamp` with AWS Cloudwatch?

My query will return:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "field": "@message",
      "value": "INFO:     10.0.0.30:35028 - \"POST /search HTTP/1.1\" 200 OK"
    },
    {
      "field": "@ptr",
      "value": "..."
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "value": "2023-09-25 16:14:24.096"
    },
    {
      "field": "@message",
      "value": "Total: 58ms"
    },
    {
      "field": "@ptr",
      "value": "..."
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "value": "2023-09-25 16:14:24.096"
    },
    {
      "field": "@message",
      "value": "Pagination: 0ms"
    },
    {
      "field": "@ptr",
      "value": "..."
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "value": "2023-09-25 16:14:24.096"
    },
    {
      "field": "@message",
      "value": "Processing: 1ms"
    },
    {
      "field": "@ptr",
      "value": "..."
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "value": "2023-09-25 16:14:24.096"
    },
    {
      "field": "@message",
      "value": "Algolia query: 40ms"
    },
    {
      "field": "@ptr",
      "value": "..."
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "value": "2023-09-25 16:14:24.096"
    },
    {
      "field": "@message",
      "value": "Filters: 17ms"
    },
    {
      "field": "@ptr",
      "value": "..."
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "value": "2023-09-25 16:14:24.096"
    },
    {
      "field": "@message",
      "value": "Query filters:  {...}"
    },
    {
      "field": "@ptr",
      "value": "..."
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "value": "2023-09-25 16:14:24.096"
    },
    {
      "field": "@message",
      "value": "index_name:  variants"
    },
    {
      "field": "@ptr",
      "value": "..."
    }
  ],
],
"statistics": {
  "recordsMatched": 5983.0,
  "recordsScanned": 9643.0,
  "bytesScanned": 1055896.0
},
"status": "Complete"
}
```

But I would like to have:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "field": "@message",
      "value": "INFO:     10.0.0.30:35028 - \"POST /search HTTP/1.1\" 200 OK\n Total: 58ms\n Pagination: 0ms\n Processing: 1ms\n Algolia query: 40ms\n Filters: 17ms\n Query filters:  {...}\n index_name:  variants\n"
    },
    {
      "field": "@ptr",
      "value": "..."
    },
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "value": "2023-09-25 14:09:26.519"
    }
  ],
  "statistics": {
    "recordsMatched": 5983.0,
    "recordsScanned": 9643.0,
    "bytesScanned": 1055896.0
  },
  "status": "Complete"
}
```

Or maybe a list of field `message` for example.

Comment: Can you share an exact example please? And what you'd want the aggregation to look like?

Comment: Sure, I did it.
I didn't know it was impossible to print code bloc in comment

Comment: Can you please show it in JSON format? This format looks unfamiliar to me.

Comment: I added the JSON raw output
The goal is to have all message for the same timestamp in one bloc or in the same line.
Sorry if this sound a bit unclear.

Comment: This isn't doable natively; use something like a Python script - are you open to that?

Comment: I use Nushell to cleaned and aggregate my logs indeed. I wondered if it was possible to do it directly from the query. Thank you for your time!